# Is it possible to store 2 32-bit values in one long int variable?

Tags: c, long-integer, multiprecision

I want to store two 32-bit values in a single long int variable.

How would you do this on a 32-bit OS using C? Is it possible to store the data in a single long long variable? If so, how is that done?

Comment: why would not you use a structure of two 32-bit integers ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: code is already present, so I just want to know 64bit data can be store in one single long int variable or not

Comment: @Syedsma: In addition to the given answers it may interest you, that on Windows the [MAKELPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632661\(v=vs.85\).aspx) macro does this (except it combines 2x16-bit into one 32-bit word). [LOWORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632659\(v=vs.85\).aspx), [HIWORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632657\(v=vs.85\).aspx) can then later be used to extract the high and low words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a long is 64 bits on your platform,

```
int v1 = 123;
int v2 = 456;
long val = v1 << 32 | v2;
```

Comment: long may only be 32 bits. Then val == v2

Comment: "assuming a long is 64 bits on your platform". If you're running on a 64 bit box with a 64 bit compiler, a long is 64 bits.

Comment: "warning: left shift count >= width of type" - you need a cast in ther e somewhere. Also try it with `v2 = -1` and watch it blow up...

Answer (score 10):

Use an uint64_t and bitwise operators.

```
uint64_t i64;
uint32_t a32, b32;

// Be carefull when shifting the a32.
// It must be converted to a 64 bit value or you will loose the bits
// during the shift. 
i64 = ((uint64_t)a32 << 32) | b32;
```

Comment: after that can i store  i64 in long int variable

Comment: @Syedsma I think you can store it in an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @Martin Thanks! I always forget that :-) I changed the cast to a C-style one.

Comment: Failure to cast before the shift will not just loose bits. It will invoke undefined behavior because the shift amount is greater than or equal to the width of the type.

Comment: @Syedsma A `long` might be too small.

Comment: @Syedsma: an `unsigned long int` may be 32 bits, so use `#include <stdint.h>`and the types `uint64_t` and `uint32_t`, as shown. They do have the required size indicated by their names. How they map to `long` or `long long` or whatever is compiler and platform dependent, and can be found in `stdint.h`

Answer (score 0):

Unless `sizeof(long int) == 8`, the answer is no. If that equality is true, then use Kevin's or cnicutar's answer.

Comment: Not quite correct. The standard allows `INT_MIN` to be -32767 and `INT_MAX` to be 32767. So what is really required is for the type used to store the result to be twice the size of the operands (original values) at least.

Comment: @jweyrich: I understand the standard allows an int to be 16 bits in size. However, he asked if he could fit two 32bit numbers into a long int. If a long int is 4 bytes long, that would be quite difficult. Also, a long int simply must be greater or equal to the size of an int.

Comment: My point is that your answer is assuming that `int` is 32 bits, which might not be the case.