# How to store and use two 32-bit signed int in one 64-bit int?

Tags: c++, data-structures, int, bit-manipulation

First of all, I want to clarify that this question is different from the questions:

- [How to store a 64 bit integer in two 32 bit integers and convert back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810280/how-to-store-a-64-bit-integer-in-two-32-bit-integers-and-convert-back-again)
- [Is it possible to store 2 32-bit values in one long int variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027495/is-it-possible-to-store-2-32-bit-values-in-one-long-int-variable)
- [How to combine two 32-bit integers into one 64-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768890/how-to-combine-two-32-bit-integers-into-one-64-bit-integer)

That this question is store **and use**, which mean I can do this

```
int64_t score = make_score(-15, 15);
score += make_score(-5, 5); //I can use (add, subtract) the score
int32_t a = get_a(score);
assert(a == -20); //-15 -5 = -20
int32_t b = get_b(score);
assert(b == 20);//15 + 5= 20
```

This is achievable for two 16-bit int in one 32-bit int ([Stockfish did this](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/4006f2c9132db034a27a94be33070d6aaab75b24/src/types.h#L263)):

```
/// Score enum stores a middlegame and an endgame value in a single integer (enum).
/// The least significant 16 bits are used to store the middlegame value and the
/// upper 16 bits are used to store the endgame value. We have to take care to
/// avoid left-shifting a signed int to avoid undefined behavior.
enum Score : int { SCORE_ZERO };

constexpr Score make_score(int mg, int eg) {
  return Score((int)((unsigned int)eg << 16) + mg);
}

/// Extracting the signed lower and upper 16 bits is not so trivial because
/// according to the standard a simple cast to short is implementation defined
/// and so is a right shift of a signed integer.
inline Value eg_value(Score s) {
  union { uint16_t u; int16_t s; } eg = { uint16_t(unsigned(s + 0x8000) >> 16) };
  return Value(eg.s);
}

inline Value mg_value(Score s) {
  union { uint16_t u; int16_t s; } mg = { uint16_t(unsigned(s)) };
  return Value(mg.s);
}
```

I'm trying to upgrade `mg` and `eg` from `int16_t` to `int32_t` but I can't figure out how to do it, I always have trouble when ScoreA + ScoreB ruin the `eg` and `mg` inside the Score.

Here is what I tried and failed:

```
enum Score : int64_t { SCORE_ZERO };

constexpr Score make_score(int mg, int eg) {
  return Score((int)((uint64_t)eg << 32) + mg);
}

inline Value eg_value(Score s) {
  union { uint32_t u; int32_t s; } eg = { uint32_t(unsigned(s + 0x80000000) >> 32) };
  return Value(eg.s);
}

inline Value mg_value(Score s) {
  union { uint32_t u; int32_t s; } mg = { uint32_t(unsigned(s)) };
  return Value(mg.s);
}
```

Comment: If you need to pack to `int32_t` together, why don't you use a `class` or `struct`? And why do you abuse enums as integers? `Score` should better be an alias for `int64_t` instead of an enum.

Comment: Expanding on the previous comment, where and how do you use `score` as an `int64_t` and why couldn't you use a `class`, there?

Comment: @churill : I'll definitely use class for Score (and I'm not use enums as integers, Stockfish devs did that :D), but I'm trying to update old code, I migrate to class will generate more trouble for me :D

Comment: PS: depressed, I decided to migrate Score to struct to save me from the bitwise madness, strangely, I success! turn out migrate to struct is easier.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).

As the comment in the original solution pointed out, this kind of bit manipulations are a minefield of potential undefined behavior. `memcpy` allows you to get rid of those and is well understood by modern compilers, so it will still result in efficient machine code.

```
enum Score : int64_t { SCORE_ZERO };

enum Value : int32_t { FORTYTWO };

inline Score make_score(int32_t mg, int32_t eg) {
    int64_t combined;
    std::memcpy(&combined, &eg, 4);
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&combined) + 4, &mg, 4);
    return Score(combined);
}

inline Value eg_value(Score s) {
    int32_t eg;
    std::memcpy(&eg, &s, 4);
    return Value(eg);
}

inline Value mg_value(Score s) {
    int32_t mg;
    std::memcpy(&mg, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s) + 4, 4);
    return Value(mg);
}
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KnGzKj).

Comment: The correct answer imho. Few suggestions: `make_score` should be inline as well otherwise linker will complain about duplicate symbols. Also why the `reinterpret_cast`s? The parameters of `memcpy` are `void*` and every address is implictly convertible to it. Lastly instead of hardcoding `magical 4` I would recommend use of `sizeof`.

Comment: There is bug: `mg_value((Score)(make_score(0,0)-make_score(15,15)))` should return `-15`, but it return `-16`

Comment: @Resurrection You need the cast here to get the offset into the middle of the `int64_t`. With the original `Score*` pointer value you can only access addresses aligned to `sizeof(Score)`. Of course casting to `void*` instead would also work, but many compilers warn about pointer arithmetic on `void*`. Good catch about the missing `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you still have some "int" and "unsigned" keywords left that still convert into the 32 bit version. So replace each "int" with "int64_t" and each "unsigned" with "uint64_t" and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be different approach for this question**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdint>
#include<bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bitset<32> bit32[2] ={ 45 ,-415152545 };
    bitset<64> bit64;
    
    // store in 64 bit varibale
    int index=0;
    int position=0;
    for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
    {
       bit64[i] =bit32[index][i-position];
       if(i==31)
         {   index = 1; position=32; }
    }
    
    // reset 32 bit container ,index and position 
       bit32[2] ={0};
       index=0;
       position=0;
    
    
   // fetching data in 32 bit container from 64 bit and assign it into a and b .
     int32_t a;
     int32_t b;
    for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
    {
       bit32[index][i-position] = bit64[i];
       if(i==31)
         {   index = 1; position=32; }
    }
    
  
    a = bit32[0].to_ulong();
    b = bit32[1].to_ulong();
    cout<<a<<" "<<b;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use union as well:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>


union Score {
    int64_t    u64;
    int32_t    u32[2];

    Score() : u64(0) {}
    Score(int64_t v) : u64(v) {}
    Score(int32_t a, int32_t b): u32{a, b} {}

    Score & operator=(Score const & original) { if(&original != this) { u64 = original.u64; } return *this; }

    int32_t get_a() {return u32[0];}
    int32_t get_b() {return u32[1];}
    int64_t get() {return u64;}

    Score operator+(Score const & other) {
            return Score(u32[0] + other.u32[0], u32[1] + other.u32[1]);
        }

    Score & operator+=(Score const & other) {
            u32[0] += other.u32[0];
            u32[1] += other.u32[1];
            return *this;
        }
};


int main() {

    Score v(-15, 15);

    std::cout << "The size is: " << sizeof(Score) << " Bytes" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A is: " << v.get_a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B is: " << v.get_b() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "adding -5, +5" << std::endl;
    Score v1 = v + Score(-5, 5);
    std::cout << "A is: " << v1.get_a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B is: " << v1.get_b() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "adding -10, +10" << std::endl;
    v += Score(-10, 10);
    std::cout << "A is: " << v.get_a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B is: " << v.get_b() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The size is: 8 Bytes
A is: -15
B is: 15
adding -5, +5
A is: -20
B is: 20
adding -10, +10
A is: -25
B is: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

```
int64_t value;
int32_t* value1 = (int32_t*)&value;
int32_t* value2 = (int32_t*)&value + 1;
```

Example:

```
#include <cstdint>


int main() {
    int64_t value;
    int32_t* value1 = (int32_t*)&value;
    int32_t* value2 = (int32_t*)&value + 1;

    *value1 = 10; // Example
    *value2 = 20;

    return 0;
}
```